# Joining attributes from start and end point to line feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-joins

I have a line shapefile and a point shapefile that are start and end point of these line features. Now I want to join ALL attributes from both start and end points to the line shapefile.

How do I do this using QGIS?

Comment: Is a python snippet an option?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by adding a field filled with same IDs for the polyline, starting point, and end point.

Then use `Join attribute tables` tool from `Processing toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector general tools -> Join attribute tables`.

[image]

Select the polyline as input layer, starting point as input layer 2, the ID field of polyline in Target field, and the common ID field of starting point layer in Target field 2. Repeat the same process for end point layer.

However, if the starting point and end point are located in one attribute point layer, you need to use Join attribute tables only one time.

Comment: Great. But how to create that unique field for every single line, start and end point? That ID must be the same for that line and the next one and next one. How to solve that?

Comment: Are starting point layer and end point layer separated?

Comment: No, that is the same layer

Comment: Is there a unique field to distinguish between starting point and end point in the attribute table?

Comment: No, there is no unique field.

Comment: I am  not sure how big is your point field and how many points you have, but the best way is to create a unique field to distinguish between starting point and end point, for example S and E, respectively. Then select by attribute using S attribute and save as a new shapefile, and do the same for E attribute. Then use use `Join by location` between line and S point, and repeat the same for E point. It will join the line attribute with the created S point and E point.

Comment: That is a huge set of data, a country level.